# Html comes back weird after requests.post

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get a list of all of the option value="5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe6 but I can't seem to be able to use even the simplest parse methods with bs4.
I'm confused!
All this prints is empty brackets `[]`

Here's my code:

```py
dropdown_text = s.post(base_url+watchlist_url+get_user_watch_url, data=data)
#Get list of wanted market ids
soup = bs(dropdown_text.text,'lxml')
print(soup)
#pprint.pprint(soup)
test = soup.find('body')
print(test)
test = soup.findAll('option',{"value": 'US - Dow Jones Industrials Index'})[0]
print(test)
```

```
<html><body><p>{"Html":"\r\n\r\n\u003cinput name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"4kKsQ_RWnpHMezsKWCJpcnhN45rqz5wJ96JPRLcbA4r2x_Mpc8UlvP0SleR93TRexSqg1sYIBSLuIAkd1AfjQXM6q_lXjM3BkJXj9Hyn_OcKLvFCc3g25Fpv7pKrKM-3Mv1QpH7VzZRGzDLfm-gf4Q2\" /\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"inner-01\"\u003e\r\n\u003cform class=\"form form-01 try-001\" id=\"analysisForm\"\u003e\r\n    Select a Market from Your Watchlist:\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"type\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cselect id=\"WatchlistItem\" name=\"WatchlistItem\"\u003e\u003coption value=\"\"\u003eSelect Market\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption selected=\"selected\" value=\"In Order\"\u003eShow All - In Order\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"A-Z\"\u003eShow All - Alphabetical A-Z\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"Z-A\"\u003eShow All - Alphabetical Z-A\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe6\"\u003eUS - S\u0026amp;P 500 Index\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"5a2b420decfdc711085dc51d\"\u003eBitcoin Per USD\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"5653923ac7eb6e355878bfeb\"\u003eUS - Dow Jones Industrials Index\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"5a8e2222ecfdc7197c27d1a3\"
etc
```

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Comment: Looks like the server is returning JSON, not HTML (or, well, weirdly wrapped in a thin layer of HTML).

Comment: @tripleee would agree the to JSON response, wrapping is caused by the `lxml` parser.

Comment: @ieh_hei try to extract your soup from JSON response: `bs(dropdown_text.json()['Html])`

Comment: @HedgeHog Good idea but it returns the exact same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @HedgeHog Good idea but it returns the exact same thing

Not exactly the same, now you operate on the correct `soup` based on your example. *question may needs some improvment cause it is not exactly reproducable*

Main issues:

1. Your example try to operate on dict / JSON like string
2. Your selection `soup.findAll('option',{"value": 'US - Dow Jones Industrials Index'})` is looking for an attribute `value` that should be equal to `US - Dow Jones Industrials Index` but there is no one, it is the text of the tag.

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

Following should fix behavior, I used `css selectors` instead of `find_all()`, cause its more handy for me:

```
...
dropdown_text = s.post(base_url+watchlist_url+get_user_watch_url, data=data)

soup = bs(dropdown_text.json()['Html'])
soup.select('option:-soup-contains("US - Dow Jones Industrials Index")')[0].get('value')
...
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup({"Html":"\r\n\r\n\u003cinput name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"4kKsQ_RWnpHMezsKWCJpcnhN45rqz5wJ96JPRLcbA4r2x_Mpc8UlvP0SleR93TRexSqg1sYIBSLuIAkd1AfjQXM6q_lXjM3BkJXj9Hyn_OcKLvFCc3g25Fpv7pKrKM-3Mv1QpH7VzZRGzDLfm-gf4Q2\" /\u003e\r\n\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"inner-01\"\u003e\r\n\u003cform class=\"form form-01 try-001\" id=\"analysisForm\"\u003e\r\n    Select a Market from Your Watchlist:\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"type\"\u003e\r\n        \u003cselect id=\"WatchlistItem\" name=\"WatchlistItem\"\u003e\u003coption value=\"\"\u003eSelect Market\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption selected=\"selected\" value=\"In Order\"\u003eShow All - In Order\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"A-Z\"\u003eShow All - Alphabetical A-Z\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"Z-A\"\u003eShow All - Alphabetical Z-A\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe6\"\u003eUS - S\u0026amp;P 500 Index\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"5a2b420decfdc711085dc51d\"\u003eBitcoin Per USD\u003c/option\u003e\r\n\u003coption value=\"5653923ac7eb6e355878bfeb\"\u003eUS - Dow Jones Industrials Index\u003c/option\u003e"}['Html'])

soup.select('option:-soup-contains("US - Dow Jones Industrials Index")')[0].get('value')
```

###### Output

```
5653923ac7eb6e355878bfeb
```

Comment: One more question the line of code works great but when I use r'US - S\u0026amp;P 500 Index'   instead of ("US - Dow Jones Industrials Index")   Then it cant find the value

Comment: Because `\u0026amp;` is an HTML escape for just `&`